# How to get RouteParams in loader method of RouteConfig

Tags: angular, routes, loader, angular2-routing

I want something like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
   {
      path: '/example/:name',
      name: 'Example',
      loader: (params: RouteParams) => {
         let name = params.get('name');
         return _EXAMLE[name];
      }
   }
])
```

I need to have RouteParams in loader method scope.
How I can do it?

Comment: Do *what*? Describe your problem properly.

Comment: I need to have RouteParams in loader method scope

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using older deprecated router. As per new Angular Router beta release you could get current activate route information in `ActivatedRoute` instance.

```
loader: (route: ActivatedRoute) => {
   let name = route.snapshot.params['name'];
   return _EXAMLE[name];
}
```

Comment: in RC4 method loader is deleted :) Sorry

Comment: Will check the possible solution after sometime, Thanks ;)